# TypeORM find an entity by given Ids in many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have 2 entities that are related. They are chat and account. I am using postgres. I want to find a chat entity with given an account id array with 2 elements. My entities are below.

Account Entity:

```js
@Entity()
export class Account {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column({ select: false })
  password: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ select: false })
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

Chat Entity:

```js
export class Chat {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Account)
  @JoinTable()
  members: Account[];

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

This is my query:

```js
this.chatsRepository.findOne({
      relations: { members: true },
      where: [
        { members: [{ id: membersIds[0] }, { id: membersIds[1] }] },
        { members: [{ id: membersIds[1] }, { id: membersIds[0] }] },
      ],
})
```

Let me explain what I want with an example.

```js
//account entities -> so these are members as relation in chat entity
[
  { id: '1', username: 'foo' },
  { id: '2', username: 'foo2' },
];


// given ids
['1', '2'];
```

So find an entity if member ids are [1,2] and given ids are [1,2] and not find an entity if member ids are [1,2] and given ids are [1,3].

I want to compare the ids of the members with the given ids. But my query always return an entity instead of by condition matching entity.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make this relation bi-directional by adding this in the account entity.

```
@ManyToMany(() => Chat, (chat) => chat.members)
chats: Chat[];
```

You can use query builder like this

```
return this.chatsRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('chat')
    .leftJoin('chat.members', 'member')
    .where('member.id IN (:...members)', { members: membersIds })
    .getOne();
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. But this code block gives "syntax error at or near ":"" error.

Comment: Thanks again. It works but again return an entity instead of by given ids. I edited my question with an example.